# Sending POST data Android

Tags: android, post

I'm trying to make in my app opportunity to sing up in newsletter from that site http://www.rossnet.pl/Start.aspx . I'm trying to send POST data in my Android app, everything looks fine, but still email are not in newsletter list. My code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b;
private int TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    "dnn_ctr1741_ViewNewsletterSubscribe_tb_hidden",
                    "k.o.p.t.u.s@gmail.com"));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "__EVENTVALIDATION",
                            "/wEWCwLbrPQDApzVwckKApul3dEEArGyrMYCAq6r4NoEAujm+N8IApWbjNwEAsHhzqkPAqD4jIQPAv7k8bICAtH1idgOYOyKdndX8LHZqHjXpX5IdUMCNvc="));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET",
                    "dnn$ctr1741$ViewNewsletterSubscribe$lbtn_subscribe"));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dnn$ctr1741$ViewNewsletterSubscribe$tb_hidden",
                    "k.o.p.t.u.s@gmail.com"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ScriptManager_TSM",
                    ";;System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en:111e8464-2436-44db-9b34-0d84ed5253c8:ea597d4b:b25378d2"));

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(
                    client.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(),
                    TIMEOUT_MS);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.rossnet.pl/Start.aspx");
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.d("debug", "lala1");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } // with list of key-value pairs
            try {
                Log.d("debug", "test1");
                client.execute(post, new ResponseHandler(){

                    public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                        Log.d("debug", "test2");
                        return null;
                    }});
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("debug", "test3");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You're sending data to the site in the name value pairs. The site doesn't interpret the data as to put you on their mailing list. Then, what is your question? What is the response the site gives you?

Comment: What exactly is the expected response?

Comment: When you sing up to newsletter you get the email with confirmation and that is what I expect.